Move line matching string to top of the file
Need to move single line with PRM:TRG keyword to top of the file using sed
File content:
FOOBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
FIZZBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
BEBAR:PRM:TRG

Output expected:
BEBAR:PRM:TRG
FOOBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
FIZZBAR:SCN:NO_TRG


please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Why do you need to use sed?

Will it always be last? Is there guaranteed to be exactly one matching line?

@Kevin: can be anywhere in the file and there is no guarantee of one matching line

With the ed line editor, the command
/PRM:TRG/ m 0

... would move the next line matching the regular expression PRM:TRG to the first line (0 meaning "after line zero").  "The next line matching ..." means, when the editor starts up, the first line in the file matching the given regular expression.
To move all matching lines to the top of the file, you would employ the g command to execute the m command for each matching line:
g/PRM:TRG/ m 0

(This would also work in Ex, Vi and Vim, but not in BusyBox's Vi.)
From the command line, you could run this second edit command like so:
printf '%s\n' 'g/PRM:TRG/ m 0' ',p' 'Q' | ed -s file

The extra commands ,p and Q prints the modified buffer to standard output and then unconditionally exits the editor without saving. Replace the ,p and Q with w and q to silently write the result back into the original file and quit.
User Shawn noticed that this would reverse the order of the PRM:TRG lines, and that you could counter this by instead moving all lines that don't match the pattern to the end of the file with v/PRM:TRG/ m $.
Another way to fix it is to set a mark at the original first line with 1ka (the mark is a), and then move all matching lines to before that line with g/PRM:TRG/ m 'a-.

A 2-pass approach using grep: Get all lines matching PRM:TRG first, and then the ones that don't.
$ { grep 'PRM:TRG' file; grep -v 'PRM:TRG' file; }
BEBAR:PRM:TRG
FOOBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
FIZZBAR:SCN:NO_TRG


With sed: Print each line matching PRM:TRG as you come across them, and store all other lines in the hold space.  Once you run out of lines to read, swap in the hold space and output it (the s command at the end gets rid of the initial newline in the hold space (which will only be there if H added anything to it) and prints it if there is anything there).
$ sed -n -e '/PRM:TRG/p' -e '//!H' -e '${x;s/\n//p;}' file
BEBAR:PRM:TRG
FOOBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
FIZZBAR:SCN:NO_TRG


A translation (more or less) of that sed command into awk:
awk '/PRM:TRG/ { print; next } { hold = hold ORS $0 } END { if (sub(ORS,"",hold)) print hold }' file

A closer translation:
awk '{ if (/PRM:TRG/) print; else hold = hold ORS $0 } END { if (sub(ORS,"",hold)) print hold }' file


I think the ed script will leave multiple matched lines in reverse order... Maybe v/PRM:TRG/ m $?

@Shawn Appreciated, thanks! I've added that with an explanation, as well as another way to fix it by marking the first line and then inserting the matching lines above that mark.

Appreciate listing different approaches!

With perl:
perl -ne 'if (/PRM:TRG/) {print} else {push @saved, $_}
          if (eof) {print for @saved}' your-file

Add a -i option to edit the file in place, or -i.back to save the original with a .back extension before doing so.
You can process more than one file that way, but you'd then need to reset @saved between each:
perl -i -ne 'if (/PRM:TRG/) {print} else {push @saved, $_}
             if (eof) {print for @saved; @saved = ()}' file1 file2...


Or use an END{} block which is arguably clearer than if(eof).

@SimonBranch, END doesn't work with -i (the print wouldn't print back into the file) or to process several files independently which is why I didn't use it here.

If you have sed then you also have awk so - using any awk and a 2-pass approach just reading 1 line at a time into memory:
$ awk 'NR==FNR { if (/PRM:TRG/) { print; skip=FNR } next } FNR!=skip' file file
BEBAR:PRM:TRG
FOOBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
FIZZBAR:SCN:NO_TRG

or using 1 pass but saving the input up to the target line in memory:
$ awk '!found{ if (/PRM:TRG/) { $0=$0 buf; found=1 } else { buf = buf ORS $0 } } found' file
BEBAR:PRM:TRG
FOOBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
FIZZBAR:SCN:NO_TRG


for the 2 pass one, shouldn't it be skip[FNR]++ (to save all matching FNRs), and ( ! FNR in skip ) in the 2nd pass condition ? in case there are more than 1 line matching "PRM:TRG" ? (your version would only skip the last line matching during the 2nd pass?) (it is unclear in the question if one should match all lines matching "PRM:TRG", or only the first one. My proposal would migrate all, in order, to the front of the file)

@OlivierDulac I'm assuming just 1 matching line as shown in the OPs example. The OP also said "Need to move single line" and IMO it's not worth adding complexity to deal with a problem the OP almost certainly doesn't have. (I know it's not much difference for the first script, but it'd be a significant change to the second one).

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my @non-match;  
             /PRM\:TRG/ ?? .put !! @non-match.push($_);  
             END  .put for @non-match;'  file

#OR:

~$ raku  -e 'my @non-match;  for lines() { 
             /PRM\:TRG/ ?? .put !! @non-match.push($_) };  
             .put for @non-match;'  file

Above are answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The first answer uses Raku's -ne non-autoprinting flags (awk-like behavior). In a BEGIN block a @non-match array is declared. The body of the loop uses Raku's Test ?? True !! False ternary operator, which immediately outputs matching lines (non-matching lines are instead pushed onto the @non-match array). Finally in an END block the @non-match array is output.
(The second answer above is similar to the first but uses Raku's lines() routine to read lines. In this case only the -e flag is required).
Sample Input:
FOOBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
FIZZBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
BEBAR:PRM:TRG

Sample Output:
BEBAR:PRM:TRG
FOOBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
FIZZBAR:SCN:NO_TRG


NOTE: While the code above is fairly simple, in true TMTOWTDI spirit you can write multiple-different Raku answers. Below a file is read line-wise into the @a array. Raku's grep is used to pull out matches, here returned as :p pairs (the key equals the line number, while the value equals the line text). Matches are saved into the @match array then printed out.  Then non-matching lines are output: the @a array is given a [ ... ] index that computes the (-) asymmetric set difference of ^@a.elems index positions (-) minus matches.
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines;   
            my @match = @a.grep( /PRM\:TRG/, :p ); 
            .put for @match.map(*.value);
            .put for @a[ keys ^@a.elems (-) @match.map(*.key) ] ;'  file

For all answers above I've tried to avoid a 2-pass approach. But in the interest of completeness, Raku's grep can return non-matching lines: see the grep link below for details.
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_??_!!
https://docs.raku.org/routine/grep
https://docs.raku.org/language/setbagmix
https://raku.org

$ sed -n '/PRM:TRG/!H;//p;${g;s/\n//;p;}' << EOF
FOOBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
FIZZBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
BEBAR:PRM:TRG
EOF
BEBAR:PRM:TRG
FOOBAR:SCN:NO_TRG
FIZZBAR:SCN:NO_TRG

For non-matches (!), append to Hold-space. Then, print matches (//). On reaching the last line ($), get the contents of the hold-space, replacing the pattern-space. Then, remove the first newline to avoid an empty line from having appended to an empty hold-space with first non-match. Finally, print those non-matching lines.
